# Why are some devices labelled Class II instead of Class III despite using ELV?

Tags: insulation, compliance, iec

For example, my table lamp has an IEC 61140 [Class II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appliance_classes) marking despite it being externally supplied with 24V.

Comment: Class 2 to which specification?

Comment: Appliance/protection classes, they are defined in IEC 61140.

Comment: If its supply is not isolated regardless of the voltage then it can't be Class III. The first requirement of Class III is to be supplied from a SELV (*separate* extra low voltage, up to 50 Vrms). Remember: The lamp (appliance) shouldn't be connected to mains, but to a separated source which has an output voltage of less than 50 Vrms.

Comment: It is supplied from an external SELV power supply.

Comment: Then the first thing comes to my mind is that the appliance might be manufactured as 
a "standard" product for different regions/countries and marked as Class II only once as "standard". So, to some countries, it might be exported with a non-isolated, cheaper power source which is still inside the boundaries of Class II. With a SELV it can be Class III but it also covers Class II. For a desktop lamp, to be honest, Class III  may not be a reason for preference, so the manufacturer wouldn't bother with putting Class III mark.